# SonarQube plugin not finding JaCoCo results

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using the Gradle plugins for JaCoCo and SonarQube yet when I execute

```
gradle clean jacoco sonarqube
```

I get an error stating

```
INFO  - Analysing ${buildDir}/build/jacoco/test.exec
WARN  - Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'jacoco'
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.0.1'
}
dependencies {
  ...
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

JaCoCo version: 0.7.1.201405082137
Gradle version: 2.12
Java version: 1.8.0_92

However, when I open the html report generated by JaCoCo it shows valid coverage results with lines highlighted properly.

The path to the test.exec file is correct and that file has contents.

What would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a version incompatibility between the version of JaCoCo that I was running and the version of SonarQube (4.5.4). Upgrading SonarQube solved the issue.